# Why is Crispus Attucks the one who gets all the attention?

Tags: united-states, american-revolution

The only name most people from the [Boston Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Massacre) is Crispus Attucks, when in fact there were five

> Crispus Attucks, Samuel Gray, James Caldwell, Samuel Maverick and Patrick Carr

So what distinguished [Crispus Attucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crispus_Attucks) from the rest of the 4?

Comment: I would think this is answered by the first couple of paragraphs of the wikipedia page on Crispus. His notablilty was that he was the first to die and, therefore, was the first American casualty in the American Revolutionary War.

Comment: I'm tempted to think there may have been base reasons for asking this question. However, after what I found looking into it I like the question much better.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can dig up, there were actually 3 people killed "instantly" in the first volley; Samuel Gray, James Caldwell, and Crispus Attucks. However, Attucks was noted as a [leader of the incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Massacre) that afternoon and evening that precipitated the shots. So not only was he the most notable of the three, but he was likely the intentional target of the shots.

I find this interesting because he's often portrayed as an unlucky bystander. Nothing could be further from the truth.

Answer (score 2):

[Crispus Attucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crispus_Attucks) was the oldest of the victims of the Boston Massacre. Born in 1723, he was the only member of the "Great Awakener" generation (of Jonathan Edwards and Benjamin Franklin), and a likely instigator of the riots. Younger, more pragmatic people were killed mainly for "showing up."

Attucks was also partly an African American (and partly Native American). As such, he was idolized by the Abolitionist movement of the 19th century that originated in Boston. It was they, and not the Revolutionary War generations, that cemented his place (retroactively) in history.